# How do I capture and write Copy activity failures to a table or file?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a Copy activity that copies data from one source to another.  Some rows in the source don't fit into the sink because of structure or data types therefore they fail correctly.

How do I capture these failed rows and write it to a table or file?

Answer (score 1):

There is a log enable property('enableCopyActivityLog' property) for copy activity in ADF that would do the needful task of copying the data into log files.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-log

Comment: Hey @bala, DId it answer your query ? In case if you want error msgs of the copy activity , you can leverage the ` @{activity('activityname').error.message} ` parameter. The below link provides a detailed descr for that : https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6712/azure-data-factory-pipeline-logging-error-details/
Note: but that wont be providing the skipped rows. That would be possible via enabling the logging property. Please don't forget to mark it as answer if the query is resolved as it might help other community members as well